# Powershell Windows Form Multilevel Combo Box

Tags: powershell, combobox

I have a windows form built in powershell thats designed to give 3 comboboxes:

CB1: Displays 5 Job descriptions

CB2: When any option from CB1 is selected its matched using $ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged and then a switch statement

CB3: When any option from CB2 is selected its matched using $ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged and then a switch statement

In this image, i have selected "Commercial Directorate" and its showing me the first match in the list "branch property trusts"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7u3J.png)

The issue with this is 2 fold.

1. i dont want it to show anything in this second combo box until i select one (stops users assuming defaults)
2. I have to click off the result and then back on it to have it display a result in the final combo box, in this example it shows "Result 1,2,3 correctly".

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7u3J.png)

Further questions:

1. i cant use the sort property on the combobox as its referencing a datasource, can i sort the data another way  ? (A-Z)
2. If i populate all 3 boxes, can i get the form to reset the 2nd and 3rd combo boxes to blank if i select a different option in CBO1? (essentially reset form)

   ```
     $initialForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
   $initialForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300)

   $descriptions = @("Select Item","Commercial Directorate","DG Directorate","Financial Directorate","Fundraising Directorate","HR Directorate")

   $ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged=
       {
           Switch ($comboBox1.text)
          {
               "Commercial Directorate"
               {
                   $envnames = @("Branch Property Trusts Programme")
               }
               "DG Directorate"
               {
                   $envnames = @("Director General","Governance & Administration")
               }

               default
               {
                   $envnames = @()
               }
           }
   $comboBox2.Remove_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged)
   $comboBox2.DataSource = $envnames
   $ComboBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged)
       }


   $ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged=
       {
           Switch ($comboBox2.text)
          {
               "Branch Property Trusts Programme"
               {
                   $envnames2 = @("Result1","Result2","Result3")
               }
               "Director General"
               {
                   $envnames2 = @("Result4","Result5")
               }

               default
               {
                   $envnames2 = @()
               }
           }
   $comboBox3.Remove_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged)
   $comboBox3.DataSource = $envnames2
   $ComboBox3.add_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged)
       }





   $comboBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
   $comboBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 90)
   $comboBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)
   $comboBox1.DataSource = $descriptions
   $ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged)

   $comboBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
   $comboBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 120)
   $comboBox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)
   $ComboBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged($ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged)

   $comboBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
   $comboBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 150)
   $comboBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180, 20)


   $initialForm.Controls.Add($comboBox1)
   $initialForm.Controls.Add($comboBox2)
   $initialForm.Controls.Add($comboBox3)
   $initialForm.ShowDialog()
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After setting the Datasource you can do:

   ```
   $combobox2.Text=""
   ```
2. 1. solves this problem too

Further questions:

1. You can just sort your datasource like this:

   ```
   $envnames = $envnames | sort
   ```

   This has to be done after assigning the values to the variable but before setting it as a datasource for your combobox.
2. To reset your other Comboboxes you could just set the Datasource to an empty array at the beginning of your `$combobox1_selectedindexchanged` block:

   ```
   $ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged=
   {
       $comboBox2.DataSource=@()
       $combobox2.Text = ""
       $combobox3.DataSource=@()
       $combobox3.Text = ""
   ....
   }
   ```

Note that i dont work with windows forms so thats just what i hacked together in 2 minutes, might not be the optimal solution

Comment: Thank you!! - i owe you a beer!

i have everything working except for the Sort , where should i place this ?

Comment: also i have one more question, i have a data source in CBO2 that matches the same name in CBO3


"Regional Operations Directorate" in CBO2 matches a result in cbo3 of "Regional Operations"

this causes me to get no result , if i change the datesource for cbo3 to Regional Operations1 it will display..

Comment: Sorry - it turns out the issue has sorted itself. :)

Comment: i was getting the below when the datasource only contained one object, it was the |sort code that was causing it, 

Exception setting "DataSource": "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource."

fixed easily with if statement.

if ($jobtitles.count -le 1) 
{} 
else
{$jobtitles = $jobtitles | sort}