# Formatting XML for relational combobox in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Hi i have the following data relationships (example only)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMBER.png)

i have over a thousand of these and i am currently referencing them inside my PS script which takes a lot of space and looks messy as hell.

cbo looks like this: [http://i.imgur.com/QQfDmhc.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/QQfDmhc.gifv)

I want to look into referencing these back to an XML file, my question is about how do i setup the relational xml?

i have no experience with XML so this is what i came up with.. from first look though it seems to solve Linking a description to a department but not a Job title to a department.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
 <roles>
  <Descriptions>
    <Description>Commercial Directorate</Description>
    <Departments>
      <Department>Finance</Department>
    <JobTitles>
      <JobTitle>BPT Case Officer</JobTitle>
      <JobTitle>Commercial Director</JobTitle>
    </JobTitles>
    </Departments>
  </Descriptions>
  <Descriptions>
    <Description>Marketing & Communications Directorate</Description>
    <Departments>
      <Department>Marketing & Communications</Department>
      <Department>Membership</Department>
    <JobTitles>
      <JobTitle>Marketing Director</JobTitle>
      <JobTitle>Marketing Manager</JobTitle>
    </JobTitles>
    </Departments>
  </Descriptions>
  </roles>
```

Can anyone help me ?

(this a follow on from my answered question here [Powershell Windows Form Multilevel Combo Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329829/powershell-windows-form-multilevel-combo-box) )

Answer (score 0):

So you have in code something along those lines? :`$jobs = @{"commdirectorate" = @{'propertytrusts' = 'L&D mentor', 'caseofficier'; 'commercial' = 'adminmanager', 'commercialdirector'}; "financedirectorate" = @{'finance' = 'accountadmin'; 'it' = 'sysadmin', 'sysengineer'}}`

Have you consider clixml or pure xml is mandatory? clixml is pretty cool as it will restore your object like you left it. It is not as easy to read as an xml from an editor but it has the same structure.

```
$jobs | Export-Clixml $filepath
$jobs | Import-Clixml $filepath
```